# Can't push values in a queue and stuck on only first and last input(python)

Tags: python, queue

I've wanted to make simple queue with self parameter, however face with output problem in which my  values I've added to the queue are only first and last on first and second positions, all in between is being ignored and  placed zero's instead(as created).

```
class Queue():
    data = []
    r = 0
    f = 0
    maxSize = 0
    size = 0
    def __init__(self,maxSize):
        self.maxSize = maxSize
        self.data = [0.0]*maxSize

    def addValue(self, val):
        if self.size == self.maxSize:
            print('Queue overflow')
        else:
            self.data[self.r] = val
            self.r =+ 1
            self.size =+ 1

    def printQ(self):
        if self.size == 0:
            print('[]')
        else:
            print('[',end='')
            for i in range(0,len(self.data)):
                print(self.data[i],end=',')
            print(']')

myQueue = Queue(7)
print(myQueue.isEmpty())
myQueue.addValue(12)
myQueue.addValue(135)
myQueue.addValue(1)
myQueue.addValue(5)
myQueue.addValue(19)
myQueue.addValue(123)
myQueue.addValue(2222)

print(myQueue.isEmpty())
myQueue.printQ()
```

The output is:

```
True
False
[12,2222,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,]
```

Comment: As a style comment: -- your code seems to mix the usage of class variables and instance variables.  There is a difference in their usage.  You even have some variables as both class and instance variables (i.e. data, max_Size) which I wouldn't suggest since it creates confusing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.r =+ 1
self.size =+ 1
```

should be

```
self.r += 1
self.size += 1
```

You should also probably be assigning:

```
data = []
r = 0
f = 0
maxSize = 0
size = 0
```

all as instance variables in the constructor instead of declaring them as class variables

Comment: you might want to explicit that `self.r =+ 1` is equivalent to `self.r = (+1)` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the use of the `r` and `[0.0]*maxSize` but this code works:

```py
class Queue():
    data = []
    f = 0
    maxSize = 0
    size = 0

    def __init__(self,maxSize):
        self.maxSize = maxSize
        self.data = []

    def addValue(self, val):
        if self.size == self.maxSize:
            print('Queue overflow')
        else:
            self.data.append(val)
            self.size =+ 1

    def printQ(self):
        if self.size == 0:
            print('[]')
        else:
            print('[',end='')
            print(",".join(str(x) for x in self.data),end='')
            print(']')

    def isEmpty(self):
      return len(self.data) == 0

myQueue = Queue(7)
print(myQueue.isEmpty())
myQueue.addValue(12)
myQueue.addValue(135)
myQueue.addValue(1)
myQueue.addValue(5)
myQueue.addValue(19)
myQueue.addValue(123)
myQueue.addValue(2222)

print(myQueue.isEmpty())
myQueue.printQ()

# prints
# True
# False
# [12,135,1,5,19,123,2222,]
```